# Where lies the difference between Dativ and Akkusativ?

Tags: grammatical-case

Can someone provide a a detailed explantion or a resource to where the difference between Dativ and Akkusativ lies and when to apply it ?

Comment: I recommend Google.

Comment: Just a hint (I know, it doesn't help a lot): The latin verb *dare* (*do, das, dare, dedi, datum*) means *to give*. The word *"**da**tive"* is derived from this verb. The latin verb *accusare* (*accuso, accusas, accusare, accusavi, accusatum*) means *to accuse, to blame*. The word *"**accusa**tive"* is derived from this verb.

Comment: Is this about the German language?

Comment: It would be helpful to know 1) what your first (home) language is 2) how many years of school you attended, and in what country. - I am asking this because the concepts of Akkusativ and Dativ are so universal - not only to indo-european languages -  that you may have a very specific linguistic background (where those concepts are not present or at least not visible in that form). Knowing this would help us give you an answer you can work with.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Concepts of A and D are not universal. In Spanish at least, one uses rather direct and indirect object respectively. Also I doulbt English has a natural A and D.

Answer (score 3):

German Wikipedia provides a good example, when you search for "Akkusativ".

> Ich gebe dem Mann seinen Hut zurück.

It's all a question of how you ask for something. There's three subjects/objects in that sentence you can ask for.

> **Wer** gibt etwas zurück? - **Ich**.

This is the first case, Nominativ, you ask who does something.

> **Wem** gebe ich etwas zurück? - **Dem** Mann.

This is the third case, the Dativ, you ask who e.g. is the target of an action.

> **Was** gebe ich zurück? - **Den** Hut.

Fourth case, the Akkusativ, you ask what e.g. is traded.

The second case, Genitiv, would be:

> **Wessen** Hut ist das? - Der Hut **des** Mannes.

You ask, whose property something is.

Comment: You wrote: *"Genitiv: You ask, whom something belongs to":* Let's try: "WEM gehört der Hut?" - "Der Hut gehört DEM MANN". - This is one of the most used usages of DATIVE case in German! You get the genitive the same way as you get it in English: You have to ask WHO'S hat this is.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: I guess you know the book "Der Dativ ist dem Genitiv sein Tod"...

Comment: @Hubert: you meant *WHOSE*, not *WHO'S*. The latter means *who is*.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: I clarified the english translation, thanks for the hint.

Comment: Native speakers have a gut feeling when to use "wem?" and when to use "wen?/was?"; so it's natural for them to learn that it's a Dativ if you ask "wem?" and an Akkusativ if you ask "wen?/was?". Unfortunately, for somebody who is used to a mostly caseless language, the difference between "wem?" and "wen?/was?" is just as obscure as the difference between Dativ and Akkusativ.